# How to kill spawned child process in ruby/bash script

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, raspberry-pi, spawn

I'm pretty new to Linux world in general. I'm trying to build a little script for the RaspPi that records audio and plays it back. It does a lot more, but that is the part I'm having trouble with. Here's a stripped down version of the relevant code

```
def start_recording
  @file = rand(1000).to_s+".wav"
  @pid = Process.spawn("sudo arecord > #{@file}")
end

def stop_recording
  Process.kill('TERM', @pid)
end

def recording_looper
  start_recording
  interrupted = false
  timer = Time.now
  trap("INT") { interrupted = true }
  until interrupted || (Time.now > timer + 5) do
    #do nothing
  end
  stop_recording
  get_input_from_user
end
```

Basically the looper works as expected, either captures the Control-C from user or stops the recording itself after 5 seconds, but the Process.kill command does not seem to work. If I listen to the wavs in another terminal window they just keep going and going. How do I properly kill that spawned record process?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `sudo` in your command-line, `sudo` will terminate once it has started the requested command. The PID stored in `@pid` will be that of `sudo` not that of the `arecord` process.

Additionally, processes started with `sudo` belong to another user (usually `root`). You will probably not have the permissions to kill them.

The easiest solution to your problem might be to find a way that doesn't require `sudo`. There's no obvious reason why `root` permissions would be required here.

Comment: The sudo process stays around as the owner of the subprocess. You can see this with `ps auxf` to see the `sudo` process and sub process. You are correct, though, that it's owned by root and you can't kill it. For my example, I used `sudo /bin/bash`, but maybe this behaves differently for other processes?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a `bash` example demonstrating that you can `sudo kill` the process (I did this on Ubuntu):

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u `whoami` sleep 600 &

pid=$!

echo "Processes before kill:"
ps axf | grep sudo | grep -v grep
ps axf | grep sleep | grep -v grep

sudo kill $pid

echo "Processes after kill (should be empty):"
ps axf | grep sudo | grep -v grep
ps axf | grep sleep | grep -v grep
```

This is the result:

```
$ ./test.sh 
Processes before kill:
27275 pts/26   S+     0:00          |   |       \_ sudo -u username sleep 600
27275 pts/26   S+     0:00          |   |       \_ sudo -u username sleep 600
27279 pts/26   S+     0:00          |   |       |   \_ sleep 600
Processes after kill (should be empty):
```

So, to kill it, you could do another command to `sudo kill` it in Ruby or Bash.